# Help with Formalizing a Diagram in Category Theory

Tags: category-theory

I'm working on a particular type of diagram using category theory, but I'm confused right now about a part of this diagram and how to properly formalize it.

The situation is the following: I have two categories, $D$ and $G$ ($G$ containing only one object) and a functor $F$ from $D$ to $G$. I have also a representable functor $R: G \to Sets$, and another (general) functor $W: D \to Sets$. So from the point of view of the sets, the situation is a bit like this :

[image: Sets]

What I'd like to do, is to label the elements on the left with elements from $R(G)$, and also close the diagram so that everything commutes.

**How can I do this?**

Another question I had as I was investigating this problem:

**Is the passage from $W(D)$ to $R(G)$ a functor ?**

Thank you for your help !

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, but you might be wanting a natural transformation from $W$ to $RF$. Aside: are you sure you meant "representable functor"? There is only one representable functor from $G$....

Comment: There are two levels: at the level of the categories $D$ and $G$, I'm labelling arrows of $D$ with morphisms of $G$. Then, I'm using functors to $Sets$ to obtain an actual "realization" of the category $D$, which I can label with elements from $R(G)$, while keeping at the same time the relations defined at the category level. I know there is only one representable functor from $G$; the more complicated case would be with $G$ a groupoid, but I'm trying a simple case first to see how this works...